# provide reason when shell denies rsync or sftp access, instead of: protocol version mismatch, protocol incompatibility, Received message too long

Tags: rsync, sftp

When someone connects to rsync, and it's supposed to stop them, and (wrongly) echos an error message, I have output from rsync like:

```
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
```

or

```
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(600) [sender=v3.2.3]
```

And for sftp, it will instead say things like:

```
Received message too long 796226418
Ensure the remote shell produces no output for non-interactive sessions.
```

Unlike every other related question and answer I found, the output is intentional; the rsync and sftp are not supposed to work. I know why the message is there, but I don't want to remove it. I just want it to fit the protocol so the user sees it. How can I deliver a message to the user so they know what to do about it?

So imagine I have a shell that does simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# just an example denying all... in reality, you allow something

# for testing, send output to this file too
exec &> >(tee "/tmp/shell-test.${USER}.out")

if grep -q "sftp" <<< "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" || grep -q "sftp" <<< "$@"; then
    echo "sftp access is denied"
    exit 1
elif grep -q "rsync" <<< "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" || grep -q "rsync" <<< "$@"; then
    echo "rsync access is denied"
    exit 1
else
    echo "I'm sorry Dave; I'm afraid I can't do that."
    exit 1
fi
```

Here are the tests and the output:

```
root@testserver # echo /usr/local/bin/test-shell >> /etc/shells
root@testserver # useradd -s /usr/local/bin/test-shell testuser
root@testserver # mkdir ~testuser/.ssh
root@testserver # echo "$yourkeyhere" > ~testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
root@testserver # passwd testuser

you@workstation $ rsync -avP src/ testuser@testserver:bla/
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(600) [sender=v3.2.3]

root@testserver # cat /tmp/shell-test.testuser.out
rsync access is denied

you@workstation $ sftp testuser@testserver
Received message too long 796226418
Ensure the remote shell produces no output for non-interactive sessions.

root@testserver # cat /tmp/shell-test.testuser.out
sftp access is denied

you@workstation $ ssh testuser@testserver
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.
Connection to testserver closed.

root@testserver # cat /tmp/shell-test.testuser.out
I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.
```

So for rsync and sftp, to deliver an error message to the user, what can I do instead of simply echo?

Comment: have you tried echoing to STDERR (i.e., `echo >&2`)?  From experience with git I know that is required; guessing it is the same for rsync etc.

Comment: that seems to work for rsync... thanks! (not sure why I didn't notice before), but doesn't for sftp (what I mainly tested...maybe why I didn't notice for rsync)